# Entity classes created by Entity Framework and LINQ to SQL

Tags: linq-to-sql, entity-framework, ado.net-entity-data-model

HI ,

The designer creates Entity classes as partial when using LINQ to SQL and the Entity Framework. Is there some way we can create the Entity classes as .cs physical files while using LINQ to SQL or the Entity Framework

Comment: There are generated .cs files for the partial classes - but its done that way to allow you to extend the classes in a manner that will be preserved if (when!) you need to update the model. I think we need to have a broader explanation of the problem you have that you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking for file-per-class? If so, I think Damien Guard's L2S T4 templates has an option to generate one .cs file per entity class. Check out these two blog posts:

http://damieng.com/blog/2009/01/19/linq-to-sql-templates-updated-now-on-codeplex
http://damieng.com/blog/2009/11/06/multiple-outputs-from-t4-made-easy-revisited

Comment: Devart Entity Developer has the same option. http://www.devart.com/entityDeveloper/